# Can't install scikit-learn

Tags: python, installation, scikit-learn

I have ubuntu linux. 
The command `pip install -U scikit-learn` gives

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Do you have some advices to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the last error you get? (before _Cleaning up..._)

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. It worked for me by running the following commands:

sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools

sudo pip install -U scikit-learn